# Positioning of JPlayer playlist

Tags: jquery, jplayer, playlist

I wonder if i can change the position of [jplayer's playlist](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/)? I know that its addo, but didnt found any statements about changing its position to appear on the right side of the player or on the same page but not even nearly to the player..[image: Dirty mock of what i need with JPlayerPlaylist]
I know that i can write my own list and implement "playlist" functionality, but need to know that i can't do that with base playlist addon's functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it by using some DIV for playlist and implemented JPlayer's functions on that div's items, for example:

```
 Response.Write(i + " <a href='javascript:play(" + song.ID + ")' >" + song.ArtistName + " " + song.Title + " (" + song.AlbumTitle + ", " + song.Year + ")" +
                           "</a><br>");
```

Where `play()` is:

```
 function play(songId) {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: "poligon.aspx",
                data: "songId=" + songId,
                success: function (result) {
                    $(".jp-title").html(result.Text);
                    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {
                        mp3: result.MP3
                    });

                    SetNextSong(result.NextSongID);
                    SetPreviousSong(result.PreviousSongID);

                    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play", 0);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        }
```